# Cakephp - Event calendar

Tags: php, events, cakephp, calendar, cakephp-3.0

I'm coding in Cakephp 3.5 a small application, which allows you to organize events based on hours using a calendar.

For example, take the month of April, in one day there may be more events, only every 2 hours. 
Take April 17th: 
Events start at 7:00, then 9:00, 11:00, 13:00 and so on.
If the user add an event at 7:00, this time is no longer available (available only 9:00, 11:00, 13:00... ), and so it works for other hours.

Now my question is how to handle these events and use them in a calendar. There are some plugin or component to handle this ?

I hope someone can help me.

There is an example what I wanna do in Cakephp:
http://quickproductdemo.com/phpeventcal/calendar.php

Comment: You can look into [Calendar](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-calendar) plugin and improve it further.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but the problem is in the implementation of the code to make it work that way

Comment: You might be able to assign time slots here to events. But you need to figure that out on your own probably. There probably aint sth specific enough yet for your use case in the (Cake)PHP land.